# Visual C++ gives me 400 plus errors?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, directory, libraries

I just upgraded my operating system(Windows 10) and installed Visual Studio 2015. I am trying to compile a simple program and getting 400+ errors, I checked for the libraries and I set them as required, but still not sure where my problem is.. Could anyone please help?[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So you're expecting us to help you debug your code based on images?

Comment: There is no problem in the code, it is a "Hello World" program!

Comment: You don't need to do anything to have the basic includes work. You **do** however have to show us code, because we cannot possibly guess what you did wrong when we don't even know **what** you are compiling.

Comment: Okay! Please help me now..

Comment: @JesuKiranSpurgen did you check those include directories to see that they contain relevant headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If You're going to use namespace std; There is no reason to preface things with std:: you can remove that from your code or remove the namespace otherwise it's redundant and pointless and you're just making more work for yourself.
2. The use of cin.get(); is not required here as the developer prompt does not close automatically and requires you to press a key inside the prompt to actually close it. Which is basically what cin.get(); is doing as well so this is more redundancy.

And finally to answer your question you're using visual studio which means you need to do 1 of the following.

1. When you create your project a little box pops up with the Next and Finish option if you simply click next and turn off pre compiled headers your current code will work.
2. Unless you turn off pre-compiled headers you must use the following header and you must place it before all other header files

   ```
   #include "stdafx.h"
   ```

When you setup a basic visual studio project it will look like this, You can change main but you must include the microsoft header unless you turn off pre-compiled headers.

```
#include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   return 0;
}
```

Choose one of those options and your code will work :)

Comment: Which is as I've said pointless as dev command prompt that launches from visual studio does not close automatically and requires you to " press any key to continue" I understand what cin.get(); does but it's not required here.