# "newly" installed visual studio returns 408 errors on blank program of type 'cannot open source file "errno.h" '

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Having installed VS 2019 on my PC, and opening up a new project, i get 408 errors that all say it cannot open various source .h files, such as errno.h, float.h, corecrt.h, etc.  or 'the global scope has no "acosf" 'I had just installed visual studio and have no clue how it works, and have not done anything other than install it and open up a new project.
Possibly useful information:

- It was not installed in the default location, but on the D: drive
- visual studio works fine when I open it with unity to edit scripts for my unity projects, but when opening it from its desktop icon or from the start menu, i get the errors
- Unity was installed before i installed Visual studio and appears to be using a different version of visual studio somewhere else on my PC, but i cant find where it is, hence me installing it myself
- The project is a C++ project

I have already tried repairing visual studio and reinstalling it, but it did not work.
[image: 408 errors in visual studio]

Comment: There are duplicates for this.

Comment: I think you have to select the SDK version in your project settings.

Comment: @drescherjm i did have a look for questions like this but couldnt find any, could you give me a link?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36059048/visual-c-gives-me-400-plus-errors

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/401228/visual-studio-not-able-to-compile-a-simple-hello-w.html

Comment: Did you try the SDK setting yet?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489899/over-400-errors-when-using-visual-studio-c

Comment: @drescherjm no i couldnt find it, im completely new to visual studio

Comment: Project Properties->General->Windows SDK Version

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, i will try all of these

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71678439/msvs-2022-c-cannot-open-source-file-ctype-h-and-477-others)), the problem is that for some reason, MSVS is not adding the **Windows Universal CRT SDK** to the include and library paths (this SDK has the header files for things like *"float.h"* and so on).

To add it to your project, you need to add the include and lib paths in the Project settings.

In my case they were:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt <- header path
```

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64 <- library path
```

*(you can find it by searching for "float.h", and "ucrtd.lib", but be careful not to use the path for Linux headers).*

You can add these paths at: `Project Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories` **(add header path here)**

and then `Project Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library directories` **(add library path here)**.

Comment: this really solve a problem. Very strange why this happened also for me. Also reinstall all wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you could to check the version of Windows SDK in visual studio installer. And then set the appropriate version of windows sdk in the `property -> General -> windows SDK version`.

[image]

Comment: "And then set the appropriate version of windows sdk" there are many Windows SDK versions, how do I know which one is appropriate?

Comment: @Bersan You can select the most recent one. I did it and it worked.