# Default Visual Studio C++ Console App has 409 errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2019

I am attempting to start learning C++, however, Visual Studio 2019 Community Default Console app has 409 errors when I start it, and will not compile.

The default project:
[image: When I start the project]

Presssing "Local Windows Debugger"
[image]
My Visual Studio Installation
[image: My installation]

Comment: Change the SDK setting of your project to one that exists on your PC.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with selecting items in the installer or reinstalling visual studio. Its in your project settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your sdk version in your visual studio installer.  Then set the version in
*Properties -> General Configuration -> Windows SDK*

Comment: Another comment sent a link to another question that helped me understand this answer. I am currently installing a Windows 10 SDK.

Comment: That comment appears to be deleted now, this was the link, thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63139726/newly-installed-visual-studio-returns-408-errors-on-blank-program-of-type-can it runs now!

Comment: This seems to be a somewhat frequent problem even on new installs. I assume you have a SDK installed but it does not match the version selected in your project settings. Also There are multiple options in the combobox for the SDK setting. The `10.0 (latest installed version)` may fix the issue without having to worry about the exact installed version.

Comment: @OskarZyg The comment moved to the top of the question now that the question is marked as a duplicate.