# How do I fix a 'cannot open source file' error on MS Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-11

Forgive me if I leave out important information, I'm a brand new programmer, and this is my first time using Stack Overflow.

I just downloaded MS Visual Studio, and was testing it by making a basic Console App that outputs "Hello world", but when I tried to run the program, it gave me a message that said "There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?" Then, when I pressed yes I got 478 errors, nearly all of which were "E1696 cannot open source file "filename"", or, "E0282 global source has no "filename"." Is there anyone who has encountered a similar problem, and if so, do you know what is causing it / how to fix it?

Comment: If this happens with a "Hello World" application. Most likely your selected SDK (in the project settings) is not installed. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489899/over-400-errors-when-using-visual-studio-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489899/over-400-errors-when-using-visual-studio-c)

Comment: Also: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63265801/default-visual-studio-c-console-app-has-409-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63265801/default-visual-studio-c-console-app-has-409-errors)

Comment: And: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63139726/newly-installed-visual-studio-returns-408-errors-on-blank-program-of-type-can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63139726/newly-installed-visual-studio-returns-408-errors-on-blank-program-of-type-can)

Comment: If you do some search you will find a lot of similar problems. Reset the SDK version will solve the problem.