# visual studio 2019 - C++ cannot open source file

Tags: c++, include, header-files

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.4 on a Windows 10 machine.

I have established that my include files live in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include" because I can actually see them listed there. However, I get an error with the line `#include <cstdio>`.

I have tried right click on project name to bring up a context from which I chose 'Properties'. From the "Solution Project1 Property Pages", I selected "Debug Source Files" and then entered the full directory path to the include files.

I still get the error

Comment: *"However, I get an error with the line "#include "."* - what line? I don't see the code that produces the problem in your question. Nor do I see the actual error message reported by the compiler. *Both* are required if you expect us to be able to analyze the problem by first ruling out the obvious: broken *code*. [Update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66032297/edit) with a [mcve] and we may be able to help.

Comment: 2017 ≠ 2019 ... there appears to be a problem here.

Comment: I did not include the code where the error because the very first line produces the error: the line is: #include <cstdio>

Comment: the full code is #include <cstdio>

int main(){
 printf("Hello, world");
 return 0;
}

Comment: Try compiling with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as   `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. It exists in [Debian](http://debian.org/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["newly" installed visual studio returns 408 errors on blank program of type 'cannot open source file "errno.h" '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63139726/newly-installed-visual-studio-returns-408-errors-on-blank-program-of-type-can)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the directory where the headers are found to the project properties under either C/C++ -> Additional include directories or VC++ -> Include directories.

And note that you need to make sure that the directory is added for all project configurations/platforms you wish to be able to build. The Debug source files item is only so that files can be found when running the debugger and have nothing to do with the project build stage.

Comment: Which menu option should I use in order to access 'C/C++ -> Additional include directories or VC++ -> Include directories.'? I can't seem to find any menu option that leads to this.

Comment: Project -> Properties, or right click on the project node in solution explorer and select Properties (I prefer the latter because then I am certain of what I am selecting).

Comment: The version that I am using - Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.4 - does not have anything under Project -> Properties that talks about 'C/C++ -> Additional include directories or VC++ -> Include directories'. I just cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran Visual Studio Installer and noted that one of the workloads, 'Desktop development with C++' had not been activated. After activating it and downloading the required or missing binaries, I am now able to create an empty project using an example of the quintessential 'Hello World' program such as #include  int main(){printf("Hello, world");return 0;}

Answer (score 0):

`#include <cstdio>` is part of the C++ Standard Library headers, if you are getting the error `E1696: 'cannot open source file`, you might have to retarget the solution/project. Do the following:

1. Right-click the Solution in the Solution Explorer pane;
2. Retarget solution;
3. Follow the steps/press OK.

It worked for me when I couldn't find Standard Library headers, hopefully, it works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Right Click On project -> properties -> platform should be x64

1. Configuration Properties -> general -> Configuration Type should be -> Dynamic Library(.dll)
2. C/C++ -> general -> Install location of Unity/Editor/Unity Version/Editor/Data/PluginApi
3. Apply These Changes
4. There is Debug option in top bar menu select appropriate platform for me it was x64