# C++ building reports "cannot open source file" error and 580 more

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++20

I've been at this for a full day and I can't understand any of it. I feel like giving up.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "crtdbg.h"  ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\yvals.h   12  
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "ctype.h"   ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cctype    12  
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "errno.h"   ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cerrno    12  
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "float.h"   ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cfloat    11  
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "locale.h"  ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\clocale   12  
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "corecrt.h" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\crtdefs.h 10  
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "stddef.h"  ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cstddef   12  
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "stdio.h"   ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cstdio    12  
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "math.h"    ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cstdlib   12  
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "stdlib.h"  ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cstdlib   13  
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "string.h"  ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cstring   12  
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "time.h"    ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\ctime 12  
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "wchar.h"   ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cwchar    13  
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "corecrt_terminate.h"   ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\eh.h  12  
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "malloc.h"  ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\exception 32  
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "share.h"   ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\xiosbase  11  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "isalnum"   ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cctype    38  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "isalpha"   ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cctype    39  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "iscntrl"   ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cctype    40  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "isdigit"   ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cctype    41  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "isgraph"   ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cctype    42  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "islower"   ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cctype    43  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "isprint"   ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cctype    44  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "ispunct"   ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cctype    45  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "isspace"   ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cctype    46  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "isupper"   ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cctype    47  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "isxdigit"  ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cctype    48  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "tolower"   ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cctype    49  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "toupper"   ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cctype    50  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "isblank"   ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cctype    52  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "lconv" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\clocale   22  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "localeconv"    ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\clocale   23  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "setlocale" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\clocale   24  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "acosf" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 736 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "asinf" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 737 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "atanf" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 738 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "atan2f"    ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 739 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "ceilf" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 740 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "cosf"  ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 741 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "coshf" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 742 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "expf"  ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 743 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "fabsf" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 744 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "floorf"    ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 745 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "fmodf" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 746 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "frexpf"    ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 747 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "ldexpf"    ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 748 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "logf"  ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 749 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "log10f"    ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 750 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "modff" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 751 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "powf"  ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 752 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "sinf"  ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 753 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "sinhf" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 754 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "sqrtf" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 755 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "tanf"  ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 756 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "tanhf" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 757 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "acosl" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 759 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "asinl" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 760 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "atanl" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 761 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "atan2l"    ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 762 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "ceill" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 763 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "cosl"  ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 764 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "coshl" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 765 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "expl"  ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 766 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "fabsl" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 767 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "floorl"    ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 768 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "fmodl" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 769 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "frexpl"    ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 770 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "ldexpl"    ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 771 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "logl"  ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 772 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "log10l"    ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 773 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "modfl" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 774 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "powl"  ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 775 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "sinl"  ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 776 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "sinhl" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 777 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "sqrtl" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 778 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "tanl"  ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 779 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "tanhl" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 780 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "float_t"   ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 782 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "double_t"  ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 783 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "nan"   ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 814 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "acoshf"    ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 821 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "asinhf"    ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 822 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "atanhf"    ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 823 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "cbrtf" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 824 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "erff"  ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 825 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "erfcf" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 826 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "expm1f"    ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 827 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "exp2f" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 828 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "hypotf"    ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 829 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "ilogbf"    ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 830 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "lgammaf"   ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 831 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "log1pf"    ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 832 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "log2f" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 833 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "logbf" ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 834 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "llrintf"   ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 835 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "lrintf"    ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\cmath 836 
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "nearbyintf"    ConsoleApplication4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual \
```

Comment: My guess is your current active SDK is no longer installed. Check the SDK setting.

Comment: There should be several questions like this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489899/over-400-errors-when-using-visual-studio-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489899/over-400-errors-when-using-visual-studio-c) or [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63139726/newly-installed-visual-studio-returns-408-errors-on-blank-program-of-type-can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63139726/newly-installed-visual-studio-returns-408-errors-on-blank-program-of-type-can)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["newly" installed visual studio returns 408 errors on blank program of type 'cannot open source file "errno.h" '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63139726/newly-installed-visual-studio-returns-408-errors-on-blank-program-of-type-can)

Comment: The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63145578/3832970), worked for me.