# Cannot open source file on visual studio 2022

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, winsock

```
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
```

I have visual studio 2022 installed and I just downloaded the newest SDK. I am trying to use winsock (I am using parallels in m1 mac and running windows 10) and none of the libraries are working. STDIO.H is pulling up "cannot open source file".. for all headers.

Comment: Try a hello world application. If you get 400+ errors your selected windows SDK is not installed.

Comment: Related to that: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489899/over-400-errors-when-using-visual-studio-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489899/over-400-errors-when-using-visual-studio-c)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["newly" installed visual studio returns 408 errors on blank program of type 'cannot open source file "errno.h" '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63139726/newly-installed-visual-studio-returns-408-errors-on-blank-program-of-type-can)

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the header file is included in the header file directory. the C++ headers path are:

1.C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include

2.C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt

The first contains standard C++ headers such as `iostream`. The second contains legacy C headers such as `stdio.h`.

If you are going to use C++ to develop desktop applications, I recommend you to refer to my setup.

[image]

Regarding the problem that the library cannot be used, I suggest you to read this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170#to-add-the-dll-header-to-your-include-path) carefully, which explains how to use the dll. If this solution does not solve your problem, please leave a message.